# Differentiability for an integral function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, proof-writing

I can't conclude the following exercise:

> Let $f \in L^{1}[0,2]$ , $\psi:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ a function and $F[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$F(t)= \int_0^1 f(x+\psi(t))dx$$ for every $ t \in [0,1]$.
>
> - Show that if $\psi$ is continuous then $F$ is continuous.
> - Show that if $\psi \in C^{1}$ and $\psi'(t)>0$ for every $t \in [0,1]$, then $F$ is differentiable for almost every $ t \in [0,1]$.

---

- Let $s<t$: I consider the difference

$$|F(t)-F(s)| = \left| \int_0^1\Bigl[f(x+\psi(t)) - f(x+\psi(s)) \Bigr] dx \right| \leq \int_0^1 \left| f(x+ \psi(t)) - f(x+\psi(s)) \right|dx$$

Taking the limit as $s \rightarrow t^{-}$ and using the fact that $f \in L^{1}$, I can pass the limit inside the sign of integral in the rhs, and I obtain the continuity.

- Here if $f$ would be differentiable, everything would work. Since it is only $L^1$, this function can't be differentiated, so I was thinking to *split* the variables in $f(x+\psi(t))$, but I don't know how.

Any help/answer/hint is highly appreciated

Comment: Your proof of continuity is not correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why ? How can I fix it?

Comment: Continuity of $F$ requires Theorem 9.5 of Rudin's RCA. Differentiability  appears harder.

Comment: Thanks. Where is that my proof fails? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: You don't even know that $f(x+\psi (s)) \to f(x+\psi (t)$ as $s \to t$ since $f$ is not given to be continuous. Even you know this you cannot assume that the integrals converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by **@Kavi Rama Murthy**, your proof of continuity is not correct as one cannot deduce the a.e.-pointwise convergence of the integrand.

(a) For the continuity, recast the integral as

$$ F(t) = \int_{0}^{2} f(x)\mathbf{1}_{[\psi(t),\psi(t)+1]}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

and then note that now one can apply the dominated convergence theorem.

(b) The above representation also allows to solve the second part. To this end, let

$$ E = \{ u \in [0, 1] : \text{both $u$ and $u+1$ are Lebesgue points of $f$} \}. $$

If $Z$ denotes the complement of the set of Lebesgue points of $f$ in $[0, 2]$, then $Z$ has measure zero by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. Moreover,

$$[0,1]\setminus E \subseteq Z \cup (Z-1), $$

and so, $E$ has full measure in $[0,1]$. Now by the assumption, $\psi$ has a $C^1$ inverse, and so, $\psi^{-1}(E)$ also has full measure in $[0,1]$. Finally, if $t \in \psi^{-1}(E)$, then both $\psi(t)$ and $\psi(t)+1$ are Lebesgue points of $f$, and so,

$$ \frac{F(t+h) - F(t)}{h} = \frac{1}{h} \int_{\psi(t)+1}^{\psi(t+h)+1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \frac{1}{h} \int_{\psi(t)}^{\psi(t+h)} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$

converges as $h \to 0$. This completes the proof.